# Reference for Log classes

Tags: raku, cro

Line 13 of stub Routes.pm6 creates new instance of `Cro::HTTP::Log::File`

Where can I find documentation to this class? For example, if I want to have logs and errors sent to the same file?

I tried using a string for :logs, and got an error. The class wants a file handle. I looked for some documentation, but it's not obvious if there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears to be lacking documentation. As to how to write the both kinds of log to the same file:

1. Create a file handle by opening a file
2. Pass it to the `logs` named arguments in the constructor (where it will be automatically used for errors too; you only need pass `errors` if they should go to a separate file).

It will look something like:

```
my $logs = open "logs", :w;
my $logger = Cro::HTTP::Log::File.new(:$logs);
```

This can then be passed along to the `Cro::HTTP::Server`'s `after` (which sets up the middleware to run on responses).

If using `cro run`, note that it will automatically restart on changes to files within the directory where a `.cro.yml` is present, and so can might end up getting a restart every time something is logged if the log file is in the same directory as the service. [Add an ignore](https://cro.services/docs/cro-yml#Controlling_automatic_restarts) to deal with this.